# Explanation for assert macro

Tags: c++

I couldn't comment on the answer itself, so: about [Using comma to prevent the need for brace pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848590/using-comma-to-prevent-the-need-for-brace-pair/3848622#3848622)

```
 #define MY_ASSERT(expr) ((expr) || (debugbreak(), 0))
```

> Here debugbreak() returns void, but we still wish to have 0 as an rvalue.

How does (debugbreak(), 0) work to return 0? I understand that the return value of debugbreak() is discarded and 0 is returned, but debugbreak generates an exception, so how can anything be evaluated afterward? I suppose my question can be generalised to any similar binary operator where the first part being evaluated exits the program.

Comment: Please accept some answers to your previous questions by clicking the checkmark next to them. If you do so, people here will be more willing to help you out next time.

Comment: Sorry, my browser theme generally makes most elements invisible so I tend to not know about them unless I'm looking for them. Thanks for telling me, I'll go look for the accept button now. By the way, nobody commented for that question about the error I received, so if someone cares, see the last line I added to emphasise this in my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138609/why-does-main-require-braces.

Comment: Why don't you change your theme to something that actually works?

Comment: Because with the theme it's much less strain on the eyes. It's not essential to see everything, but when necessary, I turn it off because fixing the visibility of certain things is not obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing will be evaluated if the assert fires, but both expressions must have the right return type, otherwise this macro will just break compilation.

Comment: +1 In other words, you can't logical-or with a `void`, but you can with an `int`.

Answer (score 4):

It's a type system hack.

```
#define MY_ASSERT(expr) ((expr) || (debugbreak(), 0))
//   note the or operator here  ^
```

The `||` operator takes two `bool`-typed (or convertible) expressions. `debugbreak()` is `void`-typed. To make it `bool`, use the following rule:

```
(FOO, BAR)
//    ^  determines the type of the entire comma expression
```

This is the same as `{FOO; BAR}` except that a block (in braces) has no type.

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is pretty simple. He's trying to get an effect pretty much the same as if he'd written: `if (!expr) debugbreak();`. For a macro, however, he wants that as a single expression. To do that, he's using `||`, which evaluates its left argument, then if and only if that is false, evaluates the right argument -- then produces an overall result that is the logical OR of the two operands.

In this case, he doesn't really *care* about that logical OR that's produced as a result; he just wants the evaluate the left, then if it's false evaluate the right. The compiler, however *does* care -- in particular, it demands that both operands of `||` have some type that can be converted to bool (or, in C, 0 or 1).

To give the compiler that, he uses the comma operator, which evaluates its left operand, then its right operand and produces the value of the right operand as the result. That lets him get the `debugbreak()` evaluated, while the `0` keeps the compiler happy by giving it an int as the result value, which it can then OR with whatever value was produced by the `expr` to produce the result of the overall expression (which, of course, is irrelevant and almost certain to be ignored).

Comment: Warning, pedantry: "it demands that both operands of `||` have some type that can be converted to" `bool`; not 0 or 1. (Of course, a `bool` can be converted to another integer type, which will result in either a 0 or a 1.)

Comment: @GMan: Yup -- somehow when I was writing that I thought the tag said C rather than C++. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

I think what your all missing is the fact that ( A || B ) follows short circuiting rules.

If A is true then there is NO NEED to evaluate B.  Since B does not need to be evaluated DebugBreak() never gets called.

If A is false, then we HAVE to evaluate B to determine the output of ( A || B ).  There is no short circuit.  (DebugBreak(), 0) of more Appropriately (DebugBreak(), false)

http://www.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~cs132/Weekly/W02/SCBooleans.html

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zs06xbxh(VS.80).aspx